# How to CONCAT 2 fields from same table using GROUP_CONCAT DISTINCT

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to return the note fields as one string with the date at the start e.g.

`2015-01-13 Important Note!, 2014-05-04 Please Read`

Example notes table:

```
  +----+---------+-----------------+---------------------+
  | id | user_id | note            | created_at          |
  +----+---------+-----------------+---------------------+
  |  2 |  2      | Important Note! | 2015-01-13 18:28:01 |
  |  3 |  2      | Please Read     | 2014-05-04 11:18:52 |
  |  4 |  3      | Who Left This?  | 2011-01-19 12:14:57 |
  +----+---------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

I have the following SQL but I need to include the date part from the created_at column:

```
SELECT u.name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT n.note) AS notes
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN notes n ON n.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just worked it out:

```
SELECT u.name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(n.created_at, '%e %b %y'), ' ', n.note) AS notes
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN notes n ON n.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
```